# Knockout computed observables in ES6

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, ecmascript-6

I am trying out for the first time knockoutjs and babeljs and have a question on how to do computed observables properly. Both `fullName` and `fullNameComp` properties are updated whenever `firstName` and `lastName` changes so not sure about pros/cons:

```
<h2>employee</h2>

<input type="text" data-bind="value: firstName, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" />
<input type="text" data-bind="value: lastName, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" />

<p>Full name getter: <spane data-bind='text: fullName'></span></p>
<p>Full name pure computed: <span data-bind='text: fullNameComp'></span></p>
```

---

```
import ko from 'knockout';
import templateMarkup from 'text!./employee.html';

class Employee {
constructor(params) {
    this.firstName = ko.observable('John');
    this.lastName = ko.observable('Smith');
    this.fullNameComp = ko.pureComputed(function() {
        return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
      }, this);
}

get fullName() {
    return this.firstName() + ' ' + this.lastName();
}

dispose() {
    // This runs when the component is torn down. Put here any logic necessary to clean up,
    // for example cancelling setTimeouts or disposing Knockout subscriptions/computeds.
}
}

export default { viewModel: Employee, template: templateMarkup };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fullName()` function will return the same result but only when called.  The computed will always have the updated value and can be used as a trigger for other code if needed.  For example, you can subscribe to `fullNameComp` but you cannot subscribe to `fullName` as it doesn't extend from KO's observable.

If the function `fullName` meets your needs then use it.